# How to make a dynamic select based on a result set from previous step on Pentaho Kettle?

Tags: etl, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to execute a select statement based on a result set from a previous step, something like this:

select column from table where column in (previous step);

Basically this step (filter rows) will split a group of ids based on a condition. I want to make a select with those who tested false but i don't know how to select only those. The table in question, which I want to select, it's very big and it is very expensive to select all records and join with the result set, so I wish to select just the group that I need, is this even possible ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu1qt.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Comment: Can you re-write your question, unable to understand the problem.

Comment: Just did it sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me try to be more specific.

Basically I Have 3 steps as my print shows.

First step is a table input, which I select from a table.

Second step is a database lookup, which I look on other table to get some fields that I want.

And third step it's a filter rows, where I kinda make a if else statement.

After my third step (filter rows) I have 2 streams: True or False.

Each stream returns me a group of ids and other fields too but it's not that important here, I guess.

I want to make a select statement based on those ids returned from previous step (Filter rows 3° step).

Basically the behaviour that I want its similar to this query:

select *
from table
where id in ("previous step");

Where table will always be the same table, so I don't think this will be a problem or something.

And "previous step" means all ids returned after the 3° step (filter rows).

What i am doing right now is: I have another table input on the other side which I make a merge join with this result set(from 3° step). But I have to make a select of the entire table and then, join with my result set, what is very expensive, and I'm wondering if i can get the same result, but with more performance.

I don't know if I am being clear enough, but I apologize right now because english it's not my main language, but I hope you guys can understand me now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three steps to achive this.

First, use a `Memory group by` step to group ids as a field.The aggregate tyoe should be`Concatenate strings separated by ,`

Second,use a `User defined java expression` step to generate a new field contains the SQL we need.The expression may like`"SELECT id,created FROM test WHERE  order_id IN ("+ ids +")"` and `ids` is the group result from last step.

At last,we can use a `Dynamic SQL row` step to look up datas by the specified SQL.